# Who are Leia's allies in the Outer Rim?

Tags: star-wars, the-last-jedi

A major plot tool of *The Last Jedi* is:

> The Resistance are trying to contact their "allies" in the Outer Rim by transmitting a signal to them through the base on Crait. Unfortunately, there is no response from these "allies."

**Who are these allies? Other Resistance groups? Another Imperial faction? The Chiss?** Are they revealed by *The Last Jedi* or any supplemental works?

Comment: Maybe some Gungans?

Comment: Maybe, Hutts.. Relationships change when you see bigger common enemy in front of you.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because of our Future Works policy..

Comment: Your original question invited speculation, which is off-topic. I've rephrased it to ask for information from any released material, which *might* identify them.

Comment: Lando Calrissian?

Comment: @Bat this is exactly why the UK and USA allied with the Soviet Union in WW2. Because Hitler.

Comment: They have good relations with the Wookies!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There were Resistance supporters known since the time of TFA (they were the ones who donated new model X-Wings, for example). From Starwars Databank article for X-70:

> The Incom T-70 X-wing is the latest incarnation of a classic design, and the signature combat craft of the Resistance’s Starfighter Corps. Faster than the Alliance-era T-65s, Resistance X-wings are maneuverable enough to engage TIE fighters in dogfights, but powerful enough to take down capital ships. The credit-strapped Resistance relies on X-wings **donated or lent by sympathetic New Republic senators and local security forces**.

Sure, the Republic center and leadership are gone but the systems those Senators were from, as well as those "local security forces", are still around.

We don't have any canon specifics beyond that, however, until maybe novelization comes out.

Answer (score 4):

There's a description in the film's [official novelisation](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Last_Jedi:_Expanded_Edition) of who Leia was planning to contact after her base on D’Qar was destroyed. Basically no-one of any consequence.

> *They had to reach out through coded channels to Snap Wexley, Jess
>   Pava, and the other pilots Leia had sent to gather the New Republic’s
>   surviving commanders. **They needed to recruit allies from the Outer
>   Rim, contact senators and planetary leaders seeking protection from
>   the First Order,** corral military forces left leaderless by the strike
>   at Hosnian Prime, and reactivate C-3PO’s network of droid spies.*

In short, the strike at Hosnian prime was pretty effective in killing anyone who could have been of any immediate use. Noting that her messages were received but not acknowledged, the various "Outer Rim" planets she contacted evidently decided that opposing the First Order at that moment would be tantamount to sending their forces to their deaths.

Answer (score -1):

[Outer Rim Alliance](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Outer_Rim_Alliance): Perhaps this group could be the allies Leia spoke of, they literally call themselves the Outer Rim Alliance which is comprised of mainly four factions; Refugees from Artorias led by the Galfridian family & Arbeloa. New Republic Forces from Dibrook led by Admiral Bylsma. Imperial Remnant Forces from Shramar led by Captain Bristow. Along with various pirates, mercenaries & smugglers.

It's likely Lando Calrissian, Maz Katana & the Hutts could be possible allies.

Many planets in the outer rim that were fundamental in aiding the Rebel Alliance would be likely to help again too like; Ryloth, Kashyyyk, Naboo, Sullust, Bespin.

Comment: You might want to note that this "alliance" only seems to appear on one low-circulation (non-canon) comic; http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Invasion:_Revelations_5

Answer (score -9):

One of major plot holes in whole new SW saga is that there is no organized resistance to First Order except the Resistance. This was "explained" by declaring that First Order destroyed most of [New Republic Starfleet](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/New_Republic_Starfleet) in Hosnian system, and that even before that said fleet was [reduced in size](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Military_Disarmament_Act). At closer scrutiny both of this reasons are not very convincing (fleet would not be so small with First Order openly displaying their strength and it would be likely dispersed trough the Galaxy). Therefore, creators of movie tried to portray things so that Resistance is not only force capable of fighting First Order, but unfortunately for them is only force (at least for now) willing to do so. Therefore, potential allies, although not explicitly stated for now, could be first and foremost remnants of Republic forces, any other planetary forces not willing to submit to First Order, pirates, smugglers, criminals, corporate fleets. With regards to ending of the movie, there is very good chance some of them will appear in next episode.

Comment: This is not a "plot hole". It's been extensively explain in the supplementary materials that there was an intentional running-down of the military capacity of the galaxy. Then, Snoke and his crew turned up with a whole bunch of former Imperial stuff and some brand new tech from out of nowhere, somewhere in the uncharted area of the galaxy.

Comment: @Valorum Plot hole it is, because it is highly unrealistic. Scaling back military while there were no First Order is relatively ok, but when it appeared and started incursions into Republic space this would definitely cause concern, especially since civil war was fresh memory.  And bunching majority of the fleet in one system to be destroyed is also very unlikely.

Comment: Poor strategy isn't a plot hole either.

Comment: @Valorum Like it or not, this is a plot hole. Because this is not a strategy, it is half-assed attempt to explain why "good guys" who supposedly won decisively suddenly find themselves (again) in underdog position. Despite all my love for SW, narrative for episodes 7 an 8 is essentially big pile of B.S.

Comment: That fact that you don't like how it's written isn't a "plot hole", nor is the fact that her allies did something dumb. Plot hole doesn't mean what you seem to think it means.

Comment: @Valorum Plot hole is by definition is by definition something that is inconsistent and/or illogical in story. I'm sorry, but disarming yourself in face of unscrupulous enemy barely defeat just few year before, plus supposedly bunching all your ships in one system of entire Galaxy - this is not stupid, it is simply plot hole. Especially, if you consider that all those decisions were made by people like Mon Mothma who were never portrayed as being dumb.

Comment: OK we got it, you **hated** TLJ. That doesn't mean it's a plot hole.

Comment: @Lefteris008 As I said year ago, find a definition of plot hole and everything will clear up .